# Returning result of mongo search in python function

Tags: python, pymongo

I've written the following function to take a time period and return the results to the main program after running a search in mongo using the package pymongo:

```
def searchMsgByDate (mycol,option):
    dt = date.today()
    if option == "today":
        start = datetime.combine(dt, datetime.min.time())
         end = datetime.combine(dt, datetime.max.time())
    elif option == "yesterday":
        start = datetime.combine(dt, datetime.min.time()) - timedelta(days=1)
        end = datetime.combine(dt, datetime.max.time()) - timedelta(days=1)
    elif option == "week":
        start = datetime.combine( dt - timedelta(days=dt.weekday()), datetime.min.time())
        end = datetime.combine(dt, datetime.max.time())
    elif option == "month":
        start = datetime.combine( dt - relativedelta(day=1) , datetime.min.time())
        end = datetime.combine(dt, datetime.max.time())
    elif option == "year":
        start = datetime.combine( dt - relativedelta(month=1,day=1) , datetime.min.time())
        end = datetime.combine(dt, datetime.max.time())
    elif option == "forever":
        start = datetime.combine( date(1970, 1, 1) , datetime.min.time())
        end = datetime.combine(dt, datetime.max.time())
    else:
        print("Invalid option for searchMsgMain; exiting")

    result = mycol.find({"msg_date": { "$gte": start, "$lt": end}});
    record_count = 0
    for entry in result:
        record_count = record_count + 1
    if record_count > 0:
        print ("Records found =", record_count)
    else:
        print ("No records found")
    return result
```

Here is the main program that calls the function:

```
out = searchMsgByDate(mycol)
for entry in out:
   ....
   ....
```

When I do so I get nothing happening in the main program. I can confirm the result of the search in the function gives over 90 records

I think I'm doing something wrong with returning this kind of object or this is not possible. I'm able to return simple values successfully.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your example please?

Comment: yup will do now

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the results to an array and sent that back as the function return. Worked perfectly.

```
mongo_query = mycol.find({"msg_date": { "$gte": start, "$lt": end}});
record_count = 0
result = []
for entry in mongo_query:
    result.append(entry)
    record_count = record_count + 1
if record_count == 0:
    print ("No records found")
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should not have to perform a count on your own by iterating through the cursor elements. Instead you can call the db.collection.find({}).count() method. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/)

2)I am not sure what myCol is but it should be a MongoClient.database_name object. For example consider the following code snippet:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class Events:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        self.database = self.client.KKNY

    def retrieveEvents(self):
        event_names = self.database['event_names']
        return event_names.find({})
```

As you can see I initialize the MongoClient, the database name in this case is KKNY. From this point I am able to access a collection within this database by running `self.database['event_names']`.

3) Also please include the version you are using for pymongo from now on it will make our lives easier